# Through Ajax price data comes to form input text, but not the selected product's price, instead only the first price is always brought

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, php-7, laravel-5.8

I have prepared a Sales recording form whereby you first select the product/stock_name. Once this selection is made it should populate a field called unit_selling price below with that product's/stock's price that should be fetched from the stock table in DB. This, happens partly since the the price of the first stock/product is fetched and only appears in the browser console. Help me fetch the specific product's price and make it appear in the form not only console. I have attached a DB pic.

#### Create.blade.php

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <br>
    <h1>Add Sale</h1>
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'SalesController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
    <label >Product Name</label>
    <select name="product_name" class="form-control" id="stock_name">
        <option>Select Product Name</option>
        @foreach ($stocks as $stock)
            <option value="{{ $stock->stock_name }}" >{{ $stock->stock_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#stock_name").on('change', function () {
            let element = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/sales-price/getunitsellingprice',
                method: 'GET',
                data: {
                    'stock_name' : element.val(),
                },
                success: function (response) {
                       $("#unit_selling_price").val(response);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('unit_selling_price', 'Unit Selling Price')}}
    {{Form::text('unit_selling_price', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Unit Selling Price', 'id' => 'unit_selling_price'])}}
</div>
@endsection
```

#### SalesController.php

```php
public function getUnitSellingPrice(Request $request)
    {
        $stock_name = $request->input("stock_name");
        if($stock_name = null){
            return null;
        }
        $stock = Stock::where('stock_name', 'like', "%".$stock_name."%")->first();
        if ($stock == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return response()->json($stock->unit_selling_price);
    }
```

#### DB screenshot: stocks table

https://slack-files.com/TP02E38GN-FP2G2BM2S-5cb95174a0

#### Form Screenshot

https://slack-files.com/TP02E38GN-FP287UP55-0e4b4a0261

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try the following code.

In the route file( `web.php` )

```
Route::any('sales-price/getunitsellingprice/{stock_id}','SalesController@getUnitSellingPrice');
```

In controller:

```
public function getUnitSellingPrice(Request $request, $stock_id)
{

   $stock = Stock::where('stock_id', $stock_id)->first();
   if ($stock == null) {
      return null;
   }

   return response()->json($stock->unit_selling_price);
}
```

Update your blade file.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Product Name</label>
    <select name="product_name" class="form-control" id="stock_name">
    <option>Select Product Name</option>
        @foreach ($stocks as $stock)
        <option value="{{ $stock->stock_id }}">{{ $stock->stock_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#stock_name").on('change', function () {
    var stock_id = $(this).val();       
        $.ajax({
            //url: MyAppUrlSettings.MyUsefulUrl,
            url: '/sales-price/getunitsellingprice/'+stock_id,
            method: 'GET',              
            success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $("#unit_selling_price").val(response);
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the trigger here . And rewrite the line like this

```
$("#unit_selling_price").val(response.data);
```

Also to get the selected option value you have to use

```
let element = $(this+' :selected');
```

Comment: That was close. .. 
to what has made it bring a price to the form field
$("#unit_selling_price").val(response)
The issuue now is: When I select any product only the price of the first product is brought to the form field. Even if I choose the last product i get 15.0000 
Check DB here: https://files.slack.com/files-pri/TP02E38GN-FP26UB023/image.png?pub_secret=dedf9d74e7
And the form so far here : https://slack-files.com/TP02E38GN-FNNSFU62X-5a70b3e316

Comment: @shibab I have removed my let element = $(this); and put yours: let element = $(this :selected); and nothing happens at all. Infact the console does not respond as before it does not send any get. PHPStorm also shows me that the line has an issue....whats up?

Comment: @shibab nothing has happened in the response. The console still does not respond as before it does not send any GET request.